# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float

Tags: python

```
    from math import ceil


def main(y, x, z):
    sum = 0
    n = len(y)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        sum += 71*(36*z[ceil(i / 4)]**2 - (y[ceil(i / 2)/5]) - x[ceil(i / 3)-1]**3)**3
    sum1 = sum *56
    print(sum1)
    return sum

main([-0.06, 0.23, 0.34, -0.72], [0.64, 0.92, -0.94, 0.33], [0.15, 0.26, 0.4, -0.37])
```

Pycharm не компилирует, выдает ошибку написанную в теме.
Задание
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возьмите `int()` от тех значений, которые у вас в квадратных скобках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Индексы не могут быть вещественными, только целыми:

```py
sum += 71*(36*z[int(ceil(i / 4))]**2 - (y[int(ceil(i / 2)/5)]) - x[int(ceil(i / 3)-1)]**3)**3
```